# JQuery AJAX GET method request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Whenever clicking the button, target file has fetched i.e. "demo.txt" (checked in network) but file content is not displaying, what's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){

        $.ajax({url: "http://localhost/suman_php/JQ_AJAX/demo.txt", 
            type:"GET",
            success: function(data,status){
                alert(status);
                $("#div1").html(data);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button id="button">Click to get Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you're loading "text", try with: `$("#div1").text(data);` otherwise your text file will be parsed as HTML and may not be what you expect (or maybe, in which case you should rename it "demo.html")

Comment: Also, change your button to `<button type='button' id='button'>`  (edit: this makes no difference in the code provided, but would if you had a `form`, so always worth being explicit)

Comment: Note that the code you've provided works perfectly - "#div1" is updated fine when copying your code to a new page and changing the url to a local file.  So either your demo.txt is html (easily fixed by using `.text()`) or there's some other issue in your code that isn't shown here.

Comment: Could be your server, add `dataType:"text",` after your `type:` line to ensure `data` is coming back as text and no attempt is being made by jquery to coerce the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to display text file content in your Div while clicking the button.
You don't need GET method unless you are trying to get specific data from link to use it somewhere else in the backend such as using it in PHP. 
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/suman_php/JQ_AJAX/demo.txt",
            async: false,   //to wait for text to load
            dataType: "text",  // jQuery will return the text data from the file
            success: function( data, status ) {
              alert(status);
              $("#div1").html(data);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

a) I suggest you to use "method" instead of "type"

b) define an "error" function, as defined here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ that may give you some info why the request failed.

Comment: "a)" these are synonyms/aliases and makes no difference which you use

Comment: No, request is successful. File has fetched but content is not displaying

Comment: *"request is successful*" - do you get the `alert`?  If not, then add the error callback as suggested to see if there are any errors - edit: in fact, add it anyway!

Comment: a) they are, but using "type" is recommended only for older versions of jQuery. It doesnt relate to the problem, just giving a suggestion.

Comment: try `console.log(data)` to see if data is ok, and `console.log( $("#div1"))` to see if your selector is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
  $.get("http://localhost/suman_php/JQ_AJAX/demo.txt", function(data, status){
    alert(status);
    $("#show").html(data);
  });

});

});
```

What should be modified in this code to view the file content?